# tooltip for each item in dynamically generated @html.dropdownfor control in mvc3

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tooltip, dropdownlistfor

I'm working on web project in **MVC 3** with **Razor** c#.

I have used `@Html.DropDownListFor` that display item dynamically. I want to set tooltip for every item of `@Html.DropDownListFor`.

My line of code as below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Value", "Text", Model.Type), 
new { @class = "Type"})
```

Comment: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Value", "Text", Model.Type), new { class = "Type" , @Title = "toolTip"})          I have added title attribute. But I am getting same title in all items. I need different types

Comment: That will only add the tooltip tip to the `select`. In order to add tooltips you would need to create your own html helper to build the html or use jquery.

Comment: How can I use jquery here?

Comment: You add the `title` attribute to each option and set its value. What would you want the tooltip text to be?

Comment: @Rem - Please check my answer. I think its inline to what Stephen has suggested in his last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I felt curious about this question so just tried to achieve it. I created a simple example and made it work to display different tooltip on each select item hover.

Note: I am not an expert in JS side and not sure if it is an ideal way.

Here is my example code:

**MyController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult LoadCountries()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Srilanka", Value = "2" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "China", Value = "3" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Austrila", Value = "4" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "5" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "UK", Value = "6" });
        ViewData["country"] = li;
        return View();
    }
```

**LoadCountries.cshtml**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/TooltipDefinition.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

<h2>Just For Demo</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Countries", ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>)
}

<h2 id="tooltipData"></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#Countries > option").each(function () {
        var item = $(this).text();

        if (item !== "Select") {
            var tooltipText = MouseHoverText(item);
            $(this).attr("title", tooltipText);
        }
    });

</script>
```

**TooltipDefinition.js**

```
var MouseHoverText = function(id) {
    switch (id) {
        case "India":
            return "You have selected India - A country full of opportunities.";
        break;
    case "Srilanka":
        return "You have selected Srilanka - God's own country.";
        break;
    default:
        return "You have selected " + id;
    }
};
```

I guess I am not doing anything different than what you attempted. I am capturing all select items and attaching title attribute when items are loaded. The tooltip text comes from JS file. You may well be able to pass it through Model.

Sharing as it may well suits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar

I declared two classes one for model and one for holding values for each options tag of dropdown list

```
public Class Report
{
  public ReportName {get; set;}
  public IList<ReportSummaryModel> AvailableReports {get; set;}
}

public class ReportSummaryModel
{
  public ReportActualName {get; set;}
  public ReportClassName {get; set;}    
  public TextField {get; set;}
  public ValueField {get; set;}
}
```

I wanted to output ReportActualName and ReportClassName onto the options tag of dropdown list and these values varies for each options.

So therefore I wrote below HTML helper function

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList<TPageModel, TSelectListModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TPageModel> htmlHelper, 
  Expression<Func<TPageModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<TSelectListModel> selectList, Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>> textField, 
  Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>> valueField, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>>> optionsAttributes)
```

The actual call to function is mentioned below

```
@Html.DropDownList(x => x.ReportName, 
Model.AvailableReports, 
x => x.TextField, 
x => x.ValueField, 
"-- Select --", 
new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<ReportSummaryModel, object>>>{ {"data-name", x => x.ReportActualName}, {"data-class", x => x.ReportClassName}})
```

The rest of the utility functions are described below

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList<TPageModel, TSelectListModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TPageModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TPageModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<TSelectListModel> selectList, Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>> textField, Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>> valueField, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, Expression<Func<TSelectListModel, TProperty>>> optionsAttributes)
        {
            string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
            string defaultValue = string.Empty;
            ModelState modelState;
            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState))
            {
                if (modelState.Value != null)
                {
                    defaultValue = (string)modelState.Value.ConvertTo(typeof(string), null /* culture */);
                }
            }
            var listItemBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
            if (optionLabel != null)
            {
                listItemBuilder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(optionLabel, string.Empty, false, null));
            }
            /* Loop through each options
             * Convert each ListItem to an <option> tag */
            foreach (var listItem in selectList)
            {
                string text = listItem.GetType()
                                      .GetProperties()
                                      .Single(p => p.Name.Equals(ClassHelper.PropertyName(textField)))
                                      .GetValue(listItem, null)
                                      .ToString();
                string value = listItem.GetType()
                                       .GetProperties()
                                       .Single(p => p.Name.Equals(ClassHelper.PropertyName(valueField)))
                                       .GetValue(listItem, null)
                                       .ToString();
                bool isSelected = value.Equals(defaultValue);
                var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var option in optionsAttributes)
                {
                    string propertyName = ClassHelper.PropertyName(option.Value);
                    htmlAttributes.Add(option.Key, listItem.GetType()
                                                             .GetProperties()
                                                             .Single(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName))
                                                             .GetValue(listItem, null)
                                                             .ToString());
                }
                listItemBuilder.AppendLine(ListItemToOption(text, value, isSelected, htmlAttributes));
            }
            var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("select")
            {
                InnerHtml = listItemBuilder.ToString()
            };
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true /* replaceExisting */);
            return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }

//Private method copied from mvc built in helper to generate option attribute

 internal static string ListItemToOption(string text, string value, bool isSelected, IDictionary<string, string> htmlAttributes)
        {
            var builder = new TagBuilder("option")
            {
                InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text)
            };
            if (value != null)
            {
                builder.Attributes["value"] = value;
            }
            if (isSelected)
            {
                builder.Attributes["selected"] = "selected";
            }
            if (htmlAttributes != null)
            {
                builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            }

            return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }


//Utility function to get property name

public class ClassHelper
    {
        public static string PropertyName<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (body == null)
            {
                body = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
            return body.Member.Name;
        }
    }
```

Output is

```html
<select name="ReportName">
 <option>--Select--</option>
 <option value="1" data-name="NameA" data-class="classA">A</option>                  
    <option value="2" data-name="NameB" data-class="classB">B</option>                  
    <option value="3" data-name="NameC" data-class="classC">C</option>                  
    <option value="4" data-name="NameD" data-class="classD">D</option>                  
</select>
```

Comment: A `<select>` that does not bind to a property and does not post back anything. Not very useful! Spend some quality time studying the MVC source code if you want to start writing your own html helpers

Comment: I see you have now changed the output to add a `name` attribute!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it out of the box. One way is to use **js** described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23946444/1849444).

The other opportunity is to create your own Type like `SelectListItem`, but with `Title` property and create `EditorTemplate` for your Type. For this variant i provide some code:

Your Templave ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Templates.ViewModels
{
    public class SelectListItemWithTitle: SelectListItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelectListWithTitle
    {
        public SelectListWithTitle(IEnumerable<SelectListItemWithTitle> items)
        {
            Items = items;
        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItemWithTitle> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your EditorTemplate that you should place in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` with name `SelectListWithTitle.cshtml`

```
@model Templates.ViewModels.SelectListWithTitle

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<select id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.Value" selected="@item.Selected" title="@item.Title">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Your ViewModel like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public SelectListWithTitle Meal { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItemWithTitle> selectListItemsWithTitle = new List<SelectListItemWithTitle>();
    selectListItemsWithTitle.Add(new SelectListItemWithTitle { Text = "Apple", Value = "0", Title = "Fresh" });
    selectListItemsWithTitle.Add(new SelectListItemWithTitle { Text = "Orange", Value = "1", Title = "Jussy" });
    selectListItemsWithTitle.Add(new SelectListItemWithTitle { Text = "Banana", Value = "2", Title = "Yellow", Selected = true });
    selectListItemsWithTitle.Add(new SelectListItemWithTitle { Text = "Vodka", Value = "3", Title = "Russian" });
    selectListItemsWithTitle.Add(new SelectListItemWithTitle { Text = "Beer", Value = "4", Title = "Cold" });

    SelectListWithTitle sl = new SelectListWithTitle(selectListItemsWithTitle);

    ViewModel model = new ViewModel
    {
        Meal = sl
    };
    ViewData.Model = model;

    return View();
}
```

And your View Index:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Meal)
```

Don't forget to change your namespaces.

Comment: Creating a `EditorTemplate` wont work. You would need to create a custom Html Helper.

Comment: @StephenMuecke why won't work if you will use `@Html.EditorFor` instead of `@Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: Because an `EditorTemplate` does not allow you to access and change the html generated for each option (i.e. to add the `title` attribute. The @Html.DropDownListFor()` method generates the html based on `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and would not work if you substituted your own type, and it wouldn't understand a `Title` property anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke we don't get each other, i provide what i mean in answer later.

Comment: Good luck. I Assume that will be much much much later. :) And what has Darin's answer in your 2nd link have to do with the question - thats just using `DropDownList` inside an `EditorTemplate` instead of directly in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the answer. Result not so clear and light as i think at the begin... There are really a lot tricky moments with IEnumerable in templates and name and id.

Comment: OMG. And what about binding, and adding html attributes and client side validation etc. etc. [Here is the source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) for `DropDownList`. I suggest you study it.